# SQL parameterization: How does this work behind the scenes?

Tags: mysql, sql, parameterized

SQL parameterization is a hot topic nowadays, and for [a good reason](http://www.computing.co.uk/ctg/news/2173851/custom-built-web-applications-vulnerable-attack), but does it really do anything besides escaping decently?

I could imagine a parameterization engine simply making sure the data is decently escaped before inserting it into the query string, but is that really all it does? It would make more sense to do something differently in the connection, e.g. like this:

```
> Sent data. Formatting: length + space + payload
< Received data
-----
> 69 SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `username` LIKE ? AND `creation_date` > ?
< Ok. Send parameter 1.
> 4 joe%
< Ok. Send parameter 2.
> 1 0
< Ok. Query result: [...]
```

This way would simply eliminate the issue of SQL injections, so you wouldn't have to avoid them through escaping. The only other way I can think of how parameterization might work, is by escaping the parameters:

```
// $params would usually be an argument, not in the code like this
$params = ['joe%', 0];

// Escape the values
foreach ($params as $key=>$value)
    $params[$key] = mysql_real_escape_string($value);

// Foreach questionmark in the $query_string (another argument of the function),
// replace it with the escaped value.
$n = 0;
while ($pos = strpos($query_string, "?") !== false && $n < count($params)) {
    // If it's numeric, don't use quotes around it.
    $param = is_numeric($params[$n]) ? $params[$n] : "'" . $params[$n] . "'";
    // Update the query string with the replaced question mark
    $query_string = substr($query_string, 0, $pos) //or $pos-1? It's pseudocode...
                  . $param
                  . substr($query_string, $pos + 1);
    $n++;
```

If the latter is the case, I'm not going to switch my sites to parameterization just yet. It has no advantage that I can see, it's just another strong vs weak variable typing discussion. Strong typing may catch more errors in compiletime, but it doesn't really make anything possible that would be hard to do otherwise - same with this parameterization. (Please correct me if I'm wrong!)

---

Update:

- I knew this would depend on the SQL server (and also on the client, but I assume the client uses the best possible techniques), but mostly I had MySQL in mind. Answers concerning other databases are (and were) also welcome though.
- As far as I understand the answers, parameterization does indeed do more than simply escaping the data. It is really sent to the server in a parameterized way, so with variables separated and not as a single query string.
- This also enables the server to store and reuse the query with different parameters, which provides better performance.

Did I get everything? One thing I'm still curious about is whether MySQL has these features, and if query reusage is automatically done (or if not, how this can be done).

Also, please comment when anyone reads this update. I'm not sure if it bumps the question or something...

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm sure that the way that your command and parameters are handled will vary depending on the particular database engine and client library.

However, speaking from experience with SQL Server, I can tell you that parameters are preserved when sending commands using ADO.NET.  They are not folded into the statement.  For example, if you use SQL Profiler, you'll see a remote procedure call like:

```
exec sp_executesql N'INSERT INTO Test (Col1) VALUES (@p0)',N'@p0 nvarchar(4000)',@p0=N'p1'
```

Keep in mind that there are other benefits to parameterization besides preventing SQL injection. For example, the query engine has a better chance of reusing query plans for parameterized queries because the statement is always the same (just the parameter values change).

*In response to update:*
Query parameterization is so common I would expect MySQL (and really any database engine) to handle it similarly.

Based on the MySQL protocol documentation, it looks like prepared statements are handled using [COM_PREPARE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/com-prepare.html) and [COM_EXECUTE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/execute-packet.html) packets, which do support separate parameters in binary format.  It's not clear if all parameterized statements will be prepared, but it does look like unprepared statements are handled by [COM_QUERY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/com-query.html) which has no mention of parameter support.

When in doubt: test.  If you really want to know what's sent over the wire, use a network protocol analyzer like Wireshark and look at the packets.

Regardless of how it's handled internally and any optimizations it may or may not currently provide for a given engine, there's very little (nothing?) to gain from not using parameters.

Comment: +1 excellent argument - also pointing out the huge performance benefits (at least in the SQL Server environment).

Comment: Thanks for providing the update, would like to upvote again... Will probably accept this answer tonight if no other posts/updates are made.

Answer (score 3):

Parameterized query are passed to SQL implementation as parameterized query, the parameters are never concatenated to the query itself unless an implementation decided to fallback to concatenating themselves. Parameterized query avoids the need for escaping, and improves performance since the query is generic and it is more likely that a compiled form of the query is already cached by the database server.

Answer (score 2):

The straight answer is "it's implemented whatever way it's implemented in the particular implementation in question". There's dozens of databases, dozens of access layers and in some cases more than one way for the same access layer to deal with the same code.

So, there isn't a single correct answer here.

One example would be that if you use Npgsql with a query that isn't a prepared statement, then it pretty much just escapes things correctly (though escaping in Postgresql has some edge cases that people who know about escaping miss, and Npgsql catches them all, so still a gain). With a prepared statement, it sends parameters as prepared-statment parameters. So one case allows for greater query-plan reuse than another.

The SQLServer driver for the same framework (ADO.NET) passes queries through as calls to sp_executesql, which allows for query-plan re-use.

As well as that, the matter of escaping is still worth considering for a few reasons:

It's the same code each time. If you're escaping yourself, then either you're doing so through the same piece of code each time (so it's not like there's any downside to using someone else's same piece of code), or you're risking a slip-up each time.

They're also better at not escaping. There's no point going through every character in the string representation of a number looking for `'` characters, for example. But does not escaping count as a needless risk, or a reasonable micro-optimisation.

Well, "reasonable micro-optimisation" in itself means one of two things. Either it requires no mental effort to write or to read for correctness afterwards (in which case you might as well), or it's hit frequently enough that tiny savings will add up, and it's easily done.

(Relatedly, it also makes more sense to write a highly optimised escaper - the sort of string replacement involved is the sort of case where the most common approach of replacing isn't as fast as some other approaches in some languages at least, but the optimisation only makes sense if the method will be called a very large number of times).

If you've a library that includes type checking the parameter (either in basing the format used on the type, or by validation, both of which are common with such code), then it's easy to do and since these libraries aim at mass use, it's a reasonable micro-opt.

If you're thinking each time about whether parameter number 7 of an 8-parameter call could possibly contain a `'` character, then it's not.

They're also easier to translate to other systems if you want. To again look at the two examples I gave above, apart from the classes created, you can use pretty much identical code with `System.Data.SqlClient` as with `Npgsql`, though SQL-Server and Postgresql have different escaping rules. They also have an entirely different format for binary strings, date-times and a few other datatypes they have in common.

Also, I can't really agree with calling this a "hot topic". It's had a well-established consensus for well over a decade at the very least.